# Getting error while generating presigned url for SSE-C

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have created a customer key for AWS S3 Server side encryption using customer key (SSE-C).

I am able to upload the object using the key. But when I generate a presigned URL using AWS Java SDK  the URL is getting created successfully but when I hit that URL I am getting the below error.

> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`
>   
>   The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.HttpMethod;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.Headers;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SSEAlgorithm;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SSECustomerKey;
import com.amazonaws.util.Base64;
import com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils;

public class GeneratePresignedURL {

 public GeneratePresignedURL() throws IOException {
  String bucketName = "abctest";
  String keyName = "testnew.mp4";

  try {
   SSECustomerKey SSE_KEY = new SSECustomerKey("KLgsVafKowMCfKDsbIh597CmMUSoPBn6QJ8OIGxAMBw=");

   ClientConfiguration cnf = new ClientConfiguration();
   cnf.withSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType");
   AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(cnf)
     .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()).build();

   // Set the presigned URL to expire after one hour.
   java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
   long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
   expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60;
   expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

   // Generate the presigned URL.
   System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
   GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName,
     keyName).withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT).withExpiration(expiration).withSSECustomerKey(SSE_KEY);

   generatePresignedUrlRequest.setSSECustomerKeyAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.AES256);

   URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

   System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toExternalForm());
  } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
   // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
   // it, so it returned an error response.
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SdkClientException e) {
   // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
   // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

I have tried to follow the code from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-c-part-5-finale/

I have no problem in using pre-signed url for SSE S3, I am only facing issue with SSE-C

I have tried setting default encryption and other config but of no help. Any pointers would be of great help.

Thanks,
AK

Comment: You're seeing SignatureDoesNotMatch when generating the URL, or when using the generated URL?

Comment: When using the presigned url. Updated the orignal post as well

Answer (score 1):

You can not call pre-signed URL direct via browser

You need to pass headers in the request

1. x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm
2. x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key
3. x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5

Please check the document for more information
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html

> When using the presigned URL to upload a new object, retrieve an existing object, or retrieve only object metadata, you must provide all the encryption headers in your client application.

Please check the sample code calling signed URL via Unirest library
https://github.com/pavanpawar4591/s3signurlwith-sse-c

```java
public static void getPreSignedURL() throws URISyntaxException {
        java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
        long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
        expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60;
        expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

        System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, keyName)
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET).withExpiration(expiration).withSSECustomerKey(SSE_KEY);

        // generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType("video/mp4");
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.setSSECustomerKeyAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.AES256);

        URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

        System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toURI() + " With key: " + SSE_KEY);

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        //https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-c-part-4/ 
        // refer to above doc
        try {
            HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get(url.toURI().toString())
                    .header(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_CUSTOMER_ALGORITHM, SSEAlgorithm.AES256.getAlgorithm())
                    .header(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_CUSTOMER_KEY, Base64.encodeAsString(SECRET_KEY.getEncoded()))
                    .header(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_CUSTOMER_KEY_MD5,
                            Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(SECRET_KEY.getEncoded()))
                    .header("cache-control", "no-cache").header("postman-token", "d3453c38-1b59-a12e-fd97-dbe2150eadf5")
                    .asString();

            System.out.println(response.getStatus());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusText());
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
        } catch (UnirestException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pavan

Any client that needs to use SSE-C, the client must be capable of sending the Below headers.

[image]

When using the presigned URL to retrieve an existing object, or retrieve only object metadata, we need to provide all the encryption headers in your client application.

- For S3 managed or KMS managed server side encryption, we can generate a presigned URL and directly paste that into a browser or player.
- However, this is not true for SSE-C objects because in addition to
  the presigned URL, you also need to include HTTP headers that are
  specific to SSE-C objects. Therefore, you can use the presigned URL
  for SSE-C objects only programmatically.

**Upload:**

I opted for S3 managed keys instead of customer provided client key.

```
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(uploadFileName);

        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) uploadFileName.length()];

        // Reads up to certain bytes of data from this input stream into an array of
        // bytes.
        fin.read(fileContent);
        // create string from byte array

        // Specify server-side encryption.
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentLength(fileContent.length);
        objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
        PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName,
                new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent), objectMetadata);

        // Upload the object and check its encryption status.
        PutObjectResult putResult = s3Client.putObject(putRequest);
        System.out.println("Object \"" + keyName + "\" uploaded with SSE.");
```

**GET Presigned URL:**

```
    java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
    long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
    expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60;
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

    System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, keyName)
            .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET).withExpiration(expiration);

    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
    System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toURI());
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html